# how to convert from Unicode to UTF-8 in PHP?

Tags: php, file, unicode, utf-8

I saved file named "File1.txt" with the content (English and Hebrew) "שלום hello".
its encode is Unicode.
when I do "readfile" and send a header:

```
Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

the Hebrew chars disappear.
The weird part is that when I open the file again I see the Hebrew chars(Unicode supports Hebrew), and UTF-8 extends Unicode so theoretically I don't need to do any conversion. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line "its encod[ing] is Unicode" makes no sense. There are many ways Unicode can be represented in a text file (UTF-8 is one of them).

If you mean - it was saved in Notepad as Unicode, that means the file is in UTF-16LE. Send the respective header:

```
Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-16
```

And it'll work.

To answer the question in the title, normally the `iconv()` function is used in PHP to convert between encodings. A word of caution though - it might not be available on the Web server in a hosted environment.

Comment: +1, Windows's misnaming of UTF-16LE as "Unicode" has caused a lot of problems. Note that UTF-16LE isn't handled very well by PHP or web browsers; it's typically better to convert everything to UTF-8 for the the web.

Comment: Thank you, 
Is there any reason why Windows called UTF-16LE as Unicode?

Comment: In order to not scare the users too much, probably. :)