# How to read unicode text-file in PHP?

Tags: php, file-io, unicode

I have some trouble reading in a text file (saved in Unicode UTF16-LE) in my PHP script.

My PHP script is saved (for some reasons) in UTF-8.

Here is my code:

```
$lines = file("./somedir/$filename");

for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    $lines[$i] = iconv("Unicode", "UTF-8", $lines[$i]); // converting to UTF8
}

echo "[0]:".$lines[0]; // outputs CORRECT text (like "This is the first line")
echo "[1]:".$lines[1]; // outputs something like çæ¤ææ¬çææ¸ææ°ã
```

Any idea please?
I checked value of `count($lines)` and it's perfectly correct...
Thanks.

EDIT:
OK so I tried `iconv("UTF-16", "UTF-8", $lines[$i]);`
I also tried `iconv("UTF-16LE", "UTF-8", $lines[$i]);`
But still no success...

Comment: "Unicode" isn't an encoding, you can't save text in "Unicode", only in specific Unicode encodings (which include UTF-8).

Comment: @Quentin Aah OK! I have it saved in UTF16-LE. But since I didn't find list of encodings in PHP manual (File() function) I made "Unicode" :) What should I put there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055553/how-to-convert-from-unicode-to-utf-8-in-php
in windows, when you save file as Unicode, you save him as UTF-16LE.
I don't understand why, but that is fact.

Comment: "Thank you" for down-vote :-/ I was searching the Stackoverflow for 2 days but since I didn't know about that UTF8 is subgroup of Unicode, I was not able to search right keywords. Sorry for asking.... :..(

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help me to convert it to UTF-8. I also have no idea why 1. line shows correctly and 2. line goes twisted... Thanks for any help !

Comment: @Enriqe: If you find out (through comments by others) that your question is missing some important information, edit your question as well, not only put that info into a comment.

Comment: In UTF-16, a line ending is 0x000A, while in UTF-8 it is 0x0A. The file() function probably splits on 0x0A, leaving the 0x00 there, which shifts all bytes one byte left, and thus outputs garbage on every second line. You should convert your file to utf-8, before splitting it up by lines or use multibyte extensions. And, yes, I don't understand, which this question got closed. I voted for reopening.

Comment: Maybe `$lines = explode(iconv("UTF-16", "UTF-8", file_get_contents("filename_here")),"\n");` does what you intended.

Comment: Also when you write *"correct text"* give as well example for the correct text. Not only when things go wrong. So users here on site can create a better imagine their own. Also complaining inside the question about downvotes is often not working towards what you like to achieve. Just saying. Good luck!

Comment: @hakre OK, I deleted that complain. I was just upset for none usefull help and just some downvotes for unknown reason... Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PHP's [`file`](http://php.net/file) function is not able to read files with the UTF-16LE encoding. It needs to split on the line ending character but PHP does only support single-byte sequences here, UTF-16LE is a multibyte variable-length encoding that is incompatible with the line-splitting procedures encoded into the `file` function.

So you are using the wrong function for the job. That simple is the answer. Not `iconv` is the problem here, but just using `file`.

Instead you need to read in the file into a buffer, get one line after the other out of the buffer and the do the re-encoding to UTF-8.

That starts by learning about the line-separator used in that file. As PHP's file-functions (and string functions as well as the strings itself) are binary based, take the binary sequence in form of a [string](http://php.net/strings) and the [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) function to locate it.

Then split line by line out of the buffer (re-fill the buffer again from the file if it runs out of bytes) and then you can use `iconv` as outlined in the manual page (or your question, the example code you have is not looking wrong, just take care you use the right parameters so the encodings are correct).

Answer (score 7):

The following code works for me:

Just use the following function fopen_utf8 instead of fopen.

```
<?php
# http://www.practicalweb.co.uk/blog/2008/05/18/reading-a-unicode-excel-file-in-php/
function fopen_utf8($filename){
    $encoding='';
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
    $bom = fread($handle, 2);
//  fclose($handle);
    rewind($handle);

    if($bom === chr(0xff).chr(0xfe)  || $bom === chr(0xfe).chr(0xff)){
            // UTF16 Byte Order Mark present
            $encoding = 'UTF-16';
    } else {
        $file_sample = fread($handle, 1000) + 'e'; //read first 1000 bytes
        // + e is a workaround for mb_string bug
        rewind($handle);

        $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($file_sample , 'UTF-8, UTF-7, ASCII, EUC-JP,SJIS, eucJP-win, SJIS-win, JIS, ISO-2022-JP');
    }
    if ($encoding){
        stream_filter_append($handle, 'convert.iconv.'.$encoding.'/UTF-8');
    }
    return  ($handle);
} 
?>
```

[From this website](http://www.practicalweb.co.uk/blog/2008/05/18/reading-a-unicode-excel-file-in-php/)

Answer (score -2):

Here the code I use to convert Unicode to normal text format.

```
function ReadUnicodeFile($fn)    
  $fc = "";    
  $fh = fopen($fn,"rb") or die("Cannot open file for read: $fn&lt;br&gt;\n");    
  $flen = filesize($fn);    
  $bc = fread($fh, $flen);

  for ($i=0; $i&lt;$flen; $i++){    
    $c = substr($bc,$i,1);    
    if ((ord($c) != 0) && (ord($c) != 13))    
      $fc = $fc . $c;    
  }

  if ((ord(substr($fc,0,1)) == 255) && (ord(substr($fc,1,1)) == 254))    
    $fc = substr($fc,2);    
  return ($fc);    
}
```